# scipy.optimize.curve_fit can't fit non linear function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a very non-linear function with two parameters that curve_fit is not able to fit : it fits the first one but do not change the second one.

I also get the classical

```
.../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:794: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated

  category=OptimizeWarning)
```

Here is the function I am trying to fit :

```
def tand(x):
    return np.tan(x*np.pi/180.)

def sind(x):
    return np.sin(x*np.pi/180.)

def cosd(x):
    return np.cos(x*np.pi/180.)

def coeffAx(A0, alpha):
    return A0*cosd(alpha)**2.

def coeffBx(B0, alpha):
    return B0*cosd(alpha)**2.

def coeffAy(A0,alpha):
    return (1./2.)*A0*cosd(alpha)*sind(alpha)

def coeffBy(B0,alpha):
    return (1./2.)*B0*cosd(alpha)*sind(alpha)

def Growth_rate(k,alpha,A0,B0,mu,r):
    c = (r**2.-1.)/r**2.
    return (k**2./(1.+(k*cosd(alpha))**2.))*(cosd(alpha)*(coeffBx(B0,alpha) - cosd(alpha)/(mu*r**2.)) + sind(alpha)*(coeffBy(B0,alpha) - sind(alpha)/(mu*r))*c - k*cosd(alpha)*(cosd(alpha)*coeffAx(A0,alpha) + sind(alpha)*coeffAy(A0,alpha)*c))


def Get_most_unstable(Sigma,alpha,k):
    SigMax = np.amax(Sigma)
    Coord = np.argwhere(Sigma == SigMax)
    kmax = k[Coord[:,1]]
    amax = alpha[Coord[:,0]]
    return np.array([SigMax, kmax, amax])

def lambda_fit(V, C1, C2):
    A0 = 3.5
    B0 = 2
    mu = tand(35)
    # R = C2 * (V -1) + 1
    k = np.linspace(0., 0.6, 1001)
    alpha = np.array([0])
    K,ALPHA = np.meshgrid(k,alpha)
    kM = []
    for v in V:
        Sigma = Growth_rate(K,ALPHA,A0,B0,mu, C2 * (v - 1) + 1)
        kM.append(Get_most_unstable(Sigma,alpha,k)[1])
    return 2*np.pi*C1/np.array(kM)
```

And here are the data :

```
V = np.array([1.0398639 , 1.13022518, 1.27846   , 1.31943454, 1.3898527 ,1.42114085])
Lambda_trans = [18.56117382616553, 13.747212426683717, 12.149968490349218, 12.034763392608163, 11.944807729994983, 12.6708866218023]
```

This is what I obtain :

```
p, pconv = curve_fit(lambda_fit, V, Lambda_trans, p0 = [1,10], check_finite = True)

/home/gadal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:794: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)

>>> p
array([ 0.69145457, 10.        ])
>>> pconv
array([[inf, inf],

       [inf, inf]])
```

As you can see the first parameter is fitted but the second is not. What is very odd is that I can obtain very good fits using values of the second parameter between 9.5 and 10. I can't understand why curve_fit is not able to do it .. ? Any ideas ? I tried to add bounds as `bounds = ([0.5,8], [1.2,12])` but the result is the same.

Comment: What is the `if size()`? Have you varied initial conditions? probably a good idea to first "fit by eye" (plot the function for your initial guess). You could also use scipy's `differential_evolution` which might be more appropriate for such a function.

Comment: I can supply an example of using @Cleb's suggestion of using scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm to estimate initial parameters. but I also could not find "if_size()" in the code you posted - was it imported?

Comment: the if size() is an error of copy on the forum, it's not on the code, that runs well. I have initial parameters, it's what I meant by "I can obtain very good fits myself". p = [0.7, 9.5] gives a very good fit by eye !

Comment: `Coord = np.argwhere(Sigma == SigMax)` is similar to an integer truncation. If there is not enough variation in `Sigma`, it will always be the same. In this case, you could print `Sigma` and `C2` (the problem parameter) and see that `Sigma` changes too little when `C2` is varied by `curve_fit`. Effectively, your function is not smooth, and can't be optimised using the underlying curve_fit algorithms.

Comment: I understand, I did not think about that, I thought the result was enough sensible in C2 to be able to be optimized. Do you have any idea of a workaround ?